# Can't complete Battlefield 1 instalation

Tags: battlefield-1

So I was installing bf1 and there was like 1 gb left but then, the electricity power went down and it couldn't download everything.
After it went up again, I logged in and found out that it says that the game is fully installed but when I launch it, in the `Multiplayer`tab says that the game is 1% installed and still downloading but it's not and I can't find a way of manually starting the download.

Reinstalling would be a way of fixing it but I don't really want to wait for that long again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify game files in Origin (right click the game > repair):

[image]